# as3 - Difference between moving background and stage focusing on player?

Tags: actionscript-3

When you have a sidescroller and you want the player to appear like it's moving sideways. There are two ways, moving the background when pressing the keys, or making the stage follow the player whenever the player moves.

Could someone tell me what makes the big difference and which one is preferred and the safer and reliable way?

Background moving so player appears to be moving:

```
background.x = scrollX;
background.y = scrollY;
```

Stage following player:

```
background.x = -(player.x - stage.stageWidth / 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to use either method according to your design preference. Both will still have the same visual effect, but if you're looking for a performance increase tell objects to unload when they're past a certain point. That way either way you go you wont have to worry about performance. It's the number of objects you have on stage that counts when it comes to 2d side scrollers.